# Better algorithm with better Big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o

**You are given an unsorted array of n integers, and you would like to find if there are any duplicates in the array (i.e. any integer appearing more than once).**
The Algorithm is based on unsorted array of size n integers. Use of nested loop was implemented to find duplicates and the complexity is;    O (N^2)

**If we limit the input data in order to achieve some best case scenario, how can you limit the input data to achieve a better Big O complexity? Describe an algorithm for handling this limited data to find if there are any duplicates. What is the Big O complexity?**

The questions asks for the following:

1. one way of how the data can be limited.
2. How this changes your algorithm for finding duplicates, and what is the better Big O complexity.

**The answer I have come up with:**

If we limit the data to, let’s say, array size of 5 (n = 5), we could reduce the complexity to O(N).
If the array is sorted, than all we need is a single loop to compare each element to the next element in the array and this will find if duplicates exist.
Which simply means that if an array given to us is by default (or luckily) already sorted (from lowest to highest value) in this case the reduction will be from O(N^2) to O(N) as we wouldn’t need the inner loop for comparing the integers for sorting since it is already sorted therefore we could implement a single loop to compare the integers to its successor and if a duplicate is encountered, then we could, for instance, use a printf statement to print the duplicates and proceed to iterate the loop n-1 times (which would be 4)- ending the program once that has been done.

The best case in this algorithm would be O(N) simply because the performance grows linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input/ data so if we have a sorted array of size 50 (50 integers in the array) then the iteration would be n-1 (the loop will iterate 50 – 1 times) where n is the length of the array which is 50.
The running time in this algorithm increases in direct proportion to the input size. This simply means that in a sorted array, the amount of time the operations take to perform is completely dependent on the input size of the array.

***Your confirmation (on whether this is correct or not) would be grateful. I know that there are other algorithms with better complexity class but since this is more efficient than O(N^2), it would be a possible answer since it's what the question asks for.***

Comment: If you limit the size of the input, the runtime is `O(1)`.

Comment: Can't you just sort the array for a cost of `O(NlogN)` and then search through it linearly?. `O(N + N log N) = O(N log N) < O(N^2)`

Comment: @U2EF1 would this make sense: If we limit the data to array size of 2 (n = 2), we could reduce the complexity to O(1). Whether the array is sorted or not sorted, we could easily apply linear search to the array to find the duplicate in the array. Since there are only 2 elements in the array, we could perform an iteration/ loop of n-1 times to compare the value of the current element in the array to the value of the next element in the array and the best-case would be that the item is in the first location of the array. best case works fastest on "limited data"- slow/ won't on other data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22422373/2521214

Answer (score 4):

If you limit the size of the array to 5 (or 1000, or any other constant for that matter), then the complexity of your algorithm becomes `O(1)`, so limiting the size of the array is a non-starter.

What you can do, however, is limit the *values* that go into the array. If you limit them to, say, 10000, or some other small number like that, you could make an `O(N)` algorithm like this:

Make an array of booleans called `seen`. The array needs to have the size of the max value that goes into your data array. Set all elements of the `seen` array to `false`. Now go through your array `data`, check if the boolean for the corresponding value is set, and if it is, declare a duplicate. Otherwise, set the `seen` flag to `true`. This algorithm has the complexity of `O(N)` in the worst case.

You could expand this algorithm to allow any range of values, as long as the value has a good hash function. Replace the array `seen` with a hash set, and use the same algorithm. Since the time complexity of adding and retrieving data in a hash set is constant, the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm would not change.

Finally, you can sort the array, and look for duplicates in `O(N*logN)`. This algorithm has a slightly worse time complexity, but its space complexity is `O(1)` (the algorithms using hash set has space complexity of `O(N)`, which may be significant).

Comment: would this make sense: If we limit the data to array size of 2 (n = 2), we could reduce the complexity to O(1). Whether the array is sorted or not sorted, we could easily apply linear search to the array to find the duplicate in the array. Since there are only 2 elements in the array, we could perform an iteration/ loop of n-1 times to compare the value of the current element in the array to the value of the next element in the array and the best-case would be that the item is in the first location of the array. As you know, best case works fastest on "limited data"- slow/ won't on other data.

Comment: @user3418449 Discussing best case / worst case is useful only when the algorithm is correct in all cases. You cannot say "my algorithm is correct only in the best case", because best case is about timing of a universally correct algorithm, not about correctness of an algorithm that sometimes produces incorrect results.